# getting error java.lang.NullPointerException in Hibernate annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

HI I am converting XML file to annotation in Java.For that I have used below annotation code according to XML where we have used collection concept.

This is not related to any of other post which are related to handling `null` pointer exception, this is in annotated code I am looking for help.

ANSWER table:

```
 <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.sample.Answer"
             table="ANSWERS">
             <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <id name="answerId" type="java.lang.Long">
               <column name="ANSWER_ID"/>
              <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>

          <property name="questionId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="QUESTION_ID"/>
             </property>

        <set name="answerText" table="ANSWERTEXT"
                inverse="true"  fetch="select" lazy="false">
            <key>
                <column name="ANSWER_ID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.sample.AnswerText" />
        </set>
          </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Annotated code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANSWERS")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Answer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ANSWER_ID")
    private Long  answerId;

    @Column(name = "QUESTION_ID")
    private Long      questionId;

    @OneToMany
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<AnswerText> answerText = new HashSet<AnswerText>();

    }
```

ANSWERTEXT table:

```
 <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.sample.AnswerText"  table="ANSWERTEXT">
             <cache usage="read-write"/>
          <id name="answerTextId" type="java.lang.Long">
               <column name="ANSWER_TEXT_ID"/>
              <generator class="identity"/>
          </id>
          <property name="answerId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ANSWER_ID"/>
             </property>
          <property name="answerText" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ANSWER_TEXT"/>
          </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Annotated code:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "ANSWERTEXT")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AnswerText {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ANSWER_TEXT_ID")
    private Long answerTextId;

    @Column(name = "ANSWER_ID")
    private Long answerId;

    @Column(name = "ANSWER_TEXT")
    private String answerText;

    }
```

Can anybody help me out what is the error I am doing in annotated file, so I am getting `null` pointer exception.Please help me on this I am newbie to Java and hibernate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: please post complete exception, so that someone can help